# Email alerts discussion board

Tags: 2013, discussion-board

Is there a way for the user when creating a new discussion to select colleagues that they wish to email alerting them that there is a new discussion that they might be interested in?

Can this be done without a workflow?

Answer (score 1):

If its per discussion item, you could use the Alert Me option on the item and add your colleagues in the Send Alerts To field.

[Set alert on a List Item](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Create-an-alert-or-subscribe-to-an-RSS-Feed-e3e912e6-59b7-4d4c-b1d6-d85552a1e870#bmalert_createffl)

[add alert video](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=cmWeh02vrAU)
Please try the above steps in your Discussions Forum item.

Comment: IS that a workflow?

Comment: It doesn't need a workflow, its an OOB functionality. I have updated the answer with a link for more information

Comment: I have successfully added an alert and I receive and email to notify me that an alert has been created but I do not receive an email when I create an item.

Comment: Mike, you've got yo check the option to send emails when an item us created. It's mentioned in the article I posted in the answer, I have also updated with a video on how to do this in the answer. If you still don't get emails then you may want to check if your SharePoint farm is configured to send emails out.

Comment: I think it is a config issue as I can easily set up alerts on the production version of this environment.

Comment: I assume its SP 2013 you have, you can check the configuration of outgoing email this way: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263462(v=office.15).aspx